# Multiple levels discriminators OpenAPI

Tags: swagger, openapi

Greeetings and thanks for your time.
I'm doing some ReDoc documenting using OpenAPI but can't find a way to properly make two levels inheritance. This is kinda what I have:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      required:
      - pet_type
      properties:
        pet_type:
          type: string
      discriminator:
        propertyName: pet_type
        mapping:
          dogs: Dog
          cats: Cat

    Cat:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      - type: object
        # all other properties specific to a `Cat`
        properties:
          name:
            type: string
    Dog:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      - type: object
        # all other properties specific to a `Dog`
        properties:
          bark:
            type: string
          size:
            type: string
        discriminator:
          propertyName: size
          mapping:
             large: '#/components/schemas/LargeDog'
             medium: '#/components/schemas/MediumDog'
    SmallDogs:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
      - type: object
    LargeDogs:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
      - type: object
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

You are doing something weird or your example does not fully reveal the essence of the problem. For a dog size, you do not need to use the discriminator. Example below

```
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      required:
      - pet_type
      properties:
        pet_type:
          type: string
      discriminator:
        propertyName: pet_type
        mapping:
          dogs: Dog
          cats: Cat
    Cat:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      - type: object
        # all other properties specific to a `Cat`
        properties:
          name:
            type: string
    Dog:
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      - type: object
        # all other properties specific to a `Dog`
        properties:
          bark:
            type: string
          size:
            type: string
            enum:
            - large
            - medium
```